# How to extract metadata from video(m3u8) files?

Tags: android

Is there any way to extract metadata from video(m3u8) files, If exist please help me with links or source code.
 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

m3u8 is the utf8 version of m3u instead c1252 charset.

m3u is a text file as a play list file with a content like:

```
 #EXTM3U starts header and must be the first line

 #EXTINF for each playable file.
```

In this link you can view samples:

http://schworak.com/programming/music/playlist_m3u.asp

And an [overview for generalistic HTTP Streaming Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html).

Answer (score 0):

Code for the lazy dudes out there is below and detailed answered is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404669/extracting-metadata-from-hls-streamm3u8-file/19485325#19485325)

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> parseHLSMetadata(InputStream i ){

        try {
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i, "UTF-8"));
            String line;
            HashMap<String, Integer> segmentsMap = null;
            String digitRegex = "\\d+";
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(digitRegex);

            while((line = r.readLine())!=null){
                if(line.equals("#EXTM3U")){ //start of m3u8
                    segmentsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                }else if(line.contains("#EXTINF")){ //once found EXTINFO use runner to get the next line which contains the media file, parse duration of the segment
                    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(line);
                    matcher.find(); //find the first matching digit, which represents the duration of the segment, dont call .find() again that will throw digit which may be contained in the description.
                    segmentsMap.put(r.readLine(), Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0)));
                }
            }
            r.close();
            return segmentsMap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Cheers.